# how to create a list that will store many values from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python

I have a list of Dictionaries in which `airbnb[0]` is

```
{
        'room_id': '1133718',
        'survey_id': '1280',
        'host_id': '6219420',
        'room_type': 'Shared room',
        'country': '',
        'city': 'Singapore',
        'borough': '',
        'neighborhood': 'MK03',
        'reviews': 9.0,
        'overall_satisfaction': 4.5,
        'accommodates': '12',
        'bedrooms': '1.0',
        'bathrooms': '',
        'price': 74.0,
        'minstay': '',
        'last_modified': '2017-05-17 09:10:25.431659',
        'latitude': 1.293354,
        'longitude': 103.769226,
        'location': '0101000020E6100000E84EB0FF3AF159409C69C2F693B1F43F'
    }
```

how do I go about it if I want to get a list consisting of only the `room_id` Value and the `price` for each dictionary in my list of dictionaries so that I can compile those lists in my new_list?

Comment: You can use a `for` loop to iterate over all the dictionaries and do the extraction there. Did you try something which didn't work? If yes, please include that in your question too.

Comment: `value` is not a field in that dictionary, so you won't be able to store it unless it's a field you can calculate

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're after but you can make a dictionary where the key is the room_id and the value the price for each property like so:

```
room_prices = { room['room_id'] : room['price'] for room in airbnb }
```

Then you access the price for a given room like so:

```
room_id = '1133718'
room_price = room_prices[room_id]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to extract one element of the dict into a new list:

```
room_ids = [item.get('room_id') for item in airbnb]
```

Do that for all interesting ones and generate a new list of dicts, if you don't want separate lists. Or you can do all that in one loop

```
newlist = [{'room_id': item.get('room_id'), 'price': item.get('price')} for item in airbnb]
```

EDIT: Or a bit more verbose but more general:

```
mylist = [{'a': 1, 'b':2, 'c':1}, {'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c':1}, {'a': 5, 'b': 2, 'c':1}, {'b': 5}]
interesting_keys = ['a', 'b']
newlist = []
for item in mylist:
    d = dict()
    for i in interesting_keys:
        d[i] = item.get(i)
    newlist.append(d)
print(nl)
```

will output:

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 2, 'b': 2}, {'a': 5, 'b': 2}, {'a': None, 'b': 5}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want them as `tuples`:

```
new_list = [(x['room_id'], x['price']) for x in airbnb]
# returns
[('1133718', 74.0)]
```

or a `dict`:

```
new_list = [{'room_id': x['room_id'], 'price': x['price']} for x in airbnb]
# returns
[{'room_id': '1133718', 'price': 74.0}]
```

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension selecting target keys in your list of dictionaries should do the job, assuming your list contains multiple dictionaries.

```
room_info =[{
        'room_id': '1133718',
        'survey_id': '1280',
        'host_id': '6219420',
        'room_type': 'Shared room',
        'country': '',
        'city': 'Singapore',
        'borough': '',
        'neighborhood': 'MK03',
        'reviews': 9.0,
        'overall_satisfaction': 4.5,
        'accommodates': '12',
        'bedrooms': '1.0',
        'bathrooms': '',
        'price': 74.0,
        'minstay': '',
        'last_modified': '2017-05-17 09:10:25.431659',
        'latitude': 1.293354,
        'longitude': 103.769226,
        'location': '0101000020E6100000E84EB0FF3AF159409C69C2F693B1F43F'
    },
    {
        'room_id': '1133718',
        'survey_id': '1280',
        'host_id': '6219420',
        'room_type': 'Shared room',
        'country': '',
        'city': 'Singapore',
        'borough': '',
        'neighborhood': 'MK03',
        'reviews': 9.0,
        'overall_satisfaction': 4.5,
        'accommodates': '12',
        'bedrooms': '1.0',
        'bathrooms': '',
        'price': 74.0,
        'minstay': '',
        'last_modified': '2017-05-17 09:10:25.431659',
        'latitude': 1.293354,
        'longitude': 103.769226,
        'location': '0101000020E6100000E84EB0FF3AF159409C69C2F693B1F43F'
    }]

[[i['room_id'],i['price']] for i in room_info]
>>[['1133718', 74.0], ['1133718', 74.0]]
```

The result will return a nested list where each individual list contains the `room_id` and `price` detail.